# curly brace inside double quotes issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering why does this simple script would cause issue between local and live machine

**Works on local**:

```
  $foo = "fooval";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO x_test_column SET value = '" . $foo . "'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  echo mysql_insert_id(); // echos the id last inserted into the DB
```

**Works on live but not on local**:

```
  $foo = "fooval";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO x_test_column SET value = '{$foo}'";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  echo mysql_insert_id(); // echos nothing
```

Now I wanted to make it work on my local since I have to adapt what is on live. Do you have any idea what is causing the issue here? PHP version compatibility?

PHP versions:

> Local - PHP 5.5.4
>
> Live - PHP 5.2.17

**Don't rant me over the usage of mysql_query(), please, not my fault**

Comment: Stupid question, but did you check if the database is there and you can connect to?

Comment: Yes I can, I can see the database and can access it. Both live and local. So I can tell it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

You probably still need to quote the string.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO x_test_column SET value = '{$foo}'";
```

Comment: What are the php versions of your local env and server?

Comment: Also you don't really need the curly brackets unless you need to isloate the variable, like echo "Show some {$test}ing stuff";

Comment: if you echo $sql, is there any difference?

Comment: It was already like that before I even started, please see my edit on PHP ver :)

Comment: before you started?  so you haven't debugged it?  Why are you running a different php version to your live server?  Wouldn't you want it to be the same? or at least similar?  Sounds like your aware those mysql functions are deprecated as of 5.5.0 also.  I'm guessing this isn't the actual code either since you forgot the quotes around the string.  Do some echo debugging, post some real code, use a more appropriate php verson ( or the proper mysql functions ).  You only have 4 lines of code to debug...try a bit harder.